Tool for conversion of multi-lined Bash scripts to a single line
From my understanding, it is possible to convert any bash script into a single line by inserting semi-colons at the end of each line of code and removing the new-line.
Firstly - am I correct in this assumption?
Secondly, are there any tools/scripts that do this function automatically?
Note: I do not want to change any command in the Bash script, not optimize to change to pipe-based commands, nothing. Keep it as is, and be able to run it.
This is a unique situation in which I must have it in a single line no matter what.
I have tried looking online, over Google or GitHub, but was left empty-handed.

Looks like a XY problem to me.

I wish it was, the requirements are as given, I need to insert a script via a single line.

there are a lot of moments in bash, where it is complicated to convert everything to a single line automaticaly. So creation of such utility is too overcomplicated and has no sense. From other side, you can just use base64 to convert any file to single string.

In your scenario: How would you handle here-documents?

It's hard to see a realistic use case for wanting a whole bash script in a single line, so if you want to do such a conversion, you have to implement it by yourself. Warning: Make sure that you treat comments properly!

Backslash-newline needs to be handled correctly, too (so you need to be able to count backslashes as you go).

"insert a script" into what? why?

The tool I am currently using for this purpose is ChatGPT, which given the 40 or so lines of Bash per automation, is capable of turning it into a single Bash line that executes the same.
There could be differences as ChatGPT isn't inherently correct, but I have yet to find any.

I think for my specific purpose it is the same, but can you please lay out the diffrences?

You’re right, in this specific example this is the same.


am I correct in this assumption?

No. Not every newline can be replaced by ;. Counterexample:
if true; then
   echo 1
fi

cmd1 &&
# comment
cmd2

can be converted to:
if true; then echo 1; fi; cmd1 && cmd2

There is no semicolon after then. There is no semicolon after &&. Additionally comments and empty lines.

are there any tools/scripts that do this function automatically?

I am not aware of any. Additionally, I see no value in doing that.
Any script can be converted to a single line by using base64 and then decoding.
oneline=$(base64 -w0 <script.sh)
base64 -d <<<"$oneline" | bash


Pipes also can be split across multiple lines, which must not then be joined with semicolons.  Commands explicitly split across lines by use of \ must have the \ removed if the lines are joined.  And commands with heredocs require at least two lines in the shell language, though as you observe, one can encode any utterance of the shell language into a form that doesn't contain newlines if desparate.
